# Is there an API for drawing statistics in OpenGL ES on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, statistics, opengl-es

If I wanted to draw pie charts and other nice stuff, are there libraries or API's for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) - **OpenGL and OpenGL ES Debugger and Profiler**

http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBugger-iPhone.php

http://glutes.sourceforge.net/

http://www.yappa.co.jp/en/pdf/YAPPA_OpenGLES_white_paper.pdf

http://www.zeuscmd.com/tutorials/opengles/02-SettingUpYourEnvironment.php

Answer (score 0):

While not for OpenGL ES, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084632/making-graphs-with-xcode) provide some Cocoa graphing options.